# (solved)VM will not boot when virtual hard drive is attached to it

Tags: boot, virtualbox, virtualization

I am trying to access my sd card from a guest OS in a virtual machine using VirtualBox. I have followed some instructions on how to attach a virtual hard drive to the VM (https://superuser.com/questions/373463/how-to-access-an-sd-card-from-a-virtual-machine/458085), but when I boot the guest OS, It won't boot and instead this message appears:

"FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted."

When I exit the VM, go to the settings of the VM and detach the virtual hard drive, and boot it again, the guest OS boots perfectly normal.

I found my own, super stupid solution:

I went into my VMs settings > storage, and instead of selecting the virtual hard drive at the right of "Controller IDE", I detached it and attached it at the right of "Controller SATA", have no idea how this worked lol!

Comment: I think this is more a question for Superuser or Serverfault, since it's not directly about Ubuntu, but have you tried changing the boot order of the disks in the VM?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed as the virtualization host for VirtualBox (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Which OS do you use for the Guest? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: That may have been a very good solution, but I just solved the problem. (lol)